# Rule to set field as invalid in a form when ajax request returns an error

Tags: jquery, validation

I have a form in which there is a field for an IP, this form uses the jquery validation.

I want this field to be invalid when a request to a server using this IP times out or triggers an error, meaning the IP is not good.

At the moment, I have:

```
remote: function(value) {
    console.log(value);
    $.ajax({
        url: 'http://' + $('#input_ip') + ':8888/api/ping',
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(response) {
            console.log('OK');
        },
        error: function(response) {
            console.log('error');
        }
        timeout: 400
    })
}
```

At the moment, it seems that the remote condition on invalidates the field on success with a return with false value.

Is there a way to return false, thus making the field invalid passing by the error statement?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [`Promise`](https://developer.mozilla.org/he/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise)

```
remote: function(value) {
    return new Promise((res,rej) => {
        console.log(value);
        $.ajax({
            url: 'http://' + $('#input_ip') + ':8888/api/ping',
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'json',
            success: res,
            error: rej,
            timeout: 400
        })
    })
}
```

And then, you can summon it like this:

```
.remote().then(() => {/* do something on success */}).catch(() => {/* do something on failure */})
```

Comment: Javascript is not in my main skills. I'm not sure how i can integrate the summon part into a jquery validation https://jqueryvalidation.org/